# Android jni : cpp jni can't find inner class of a java class. Want to return a java class to calling cpp jni function

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am getting below error in my code. I am not able to resolve it.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.graphics.package1.**javaClass1$innerClass**" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

*I have tried different signatures such as com/graphics/package1/javaClass1$innerClass
com/graphics/package1/javaClass1/innerClass etc but, it does not solve the problem*

Java code is as below

xyz.java

```
package com.graphics.package1;

public class javaClass1 {
==========

    public class innerClass {
        public int a;
        public float b;
    }

    public innerClass getJavaClass() {

        innerClass new_innerClass = new innerClass();
        new_innerClass.a = 2;
        new_innerClass.b = 10.5;
        return new_innerClass;
    }
```

Below is my code in jni code (.cpp). This calls java function which should return a class. I have simplified the code for your easier understanding.

```
typedef struct {
   int a;
   float b;
} CppStruct;

bool checkException(JNIEnv* env) {
    if (env->ExceptionCheck()) {
        env->ExceptionDescribe(); // writes to logcat
        env->ExceptionClear();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool getClass(CppStruct* cppStruct, int num) {
    jboolean result = false;


    int status = g_JavaVM->GetEnv((void **) &envLocal, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
    if (status < 0) {
        status = g_JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&envLocal, NULL);
        if (status < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (envLocal == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    if (g_clazz == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

**// Fine the inner class of java javaClass1. This fails with exception.**
    jclass jcppStructClass = envLocal->FindClass("com/graphics/package1/**javaClass1$innerClass**");

    if (checkException(envLocal)) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TAG",
                "Exception occurred in jcppStructClass");
    }

**// next is to call the java method to get the java class object. This has not reached here but please guide here too.**
jmethodID methodID_getJavaClass = envLocal->GetMethodID(g_clazz,
        "getJavaClass", "()Lcom/graphics/package1/javaClass1/innerClass;");

if (methodID_getJavaClass != NULL) {
        jobject jCoreStatusClassObject = envLocal->CallStaticObjectMethod(g_clazz, methodID_getJavaClass, num);
        if (checkException(envLocal)) {
            __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TAG",
                    "Exception occurred in CallStaticObjectMethod");
        }
        // I will fill cppStruct but, I know this will also fail because of the signature
        g_JavaVM->DetachCurrentThread();
        return true;
    } else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try making inner class static.

Comment: static does not solve it.

Comment: I just found that I do not get this exception when I FindClassin JNI_OnLoad() but, when I I cannot do FindClass in that getClass() function. Why?

Comment: [Why didn't FindClass find my class?](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass)

Comment: @Michael. But, why FindClass() (same code) works from JNI_OnLoad and not from the function??

Comment: The page I linked to in my previous comment explains one possible reason for that.